# Google Spreadsheets on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets-api

I'm trying read a spreadsheet on appengine:

```
List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");
AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes);

Credential creds = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod());
creds.setAccessToken(accessToken.getAccessToken());

SpreadsheetService ss = new SpreadsheetService("DBM4G-demo");
ss.setOAuth2Credentials(creds);
```

The problem I'm having is setOAuth2Credentials is not a class(at least eclipse says it is not and I can't compile).  I have included gdata-spreadsheets-3.0.jar in my project.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

**OAuth issues** The google DrEdit tutorial is a good way to sort out OAuth issues for Google drive/Spreadsheet etc. It is the best OAuth tutorial I have been able to find.

**Spreadsheet Connection code** :

```
SpreadsheetService spreadsheetService = null;
spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService("mydomain.com.au-v0.2");
spreadsheetService.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
spreadsheetService.setConnectTimeout(0);
```

(I added the setConnectTimeout(0) to for development, but suspect I no longer need it. )